# Recenter buffer when clickable text is clicked?

Tags: hooks, align, help

**TASK 1:**

If I run `C-h f goto-line`(or any other function) it will open help buffer with clickable text like this.

[image]

If I click this text, it will open that file in a new buffer and it will take to that definition. But the **point will be on last line** like this.

[image]

**TASK 2:**

If I call `(recenter 0)`, it will place point in top line like this.

[image]

How can I link both of these tasks, so that every time I click on a button it will place point on top line of buffer? I couldn't find any useful hooks to do these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging through source, I failed at finding any such hook. So as a final resort you can advice the function `help-button-action` to recenter after jump.

```el
(defun my-recenter-on-find-function (orig &rest args)
  (let ((result (apply orig args)))
    (when result
      (recenter))
    result))

(advice-add 'help-button-action :around #'my-recenter-on-find-function)
```

The buttons in the help-buffer are [defined](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/help-mode.el?id=59b5723c9b613f14cd60cd3239cfdbc0d2343b18#n193) using `define-button-type`. While creating buttons one can attach additional properties to them, of these the property of interest to us is the `action` property which is called whenever a button is hit. Additionally a button can inherit from other buttons (which basically means the default values from parent are inherited), in our case all the buttons in help buffer inherit from [`help-xref`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/help-mode.el?id=59b5723c9b613f14cd60cd3239cfdbc0d2343b18#n104) button which sets the `action` property to `help-button-action`.

All this is important because the buttons in help-buffer define the properties `help-function` and `help-args`, which are used by `help-button-action` to jump to the definition. The interesting button here is [`help-function-def`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/help-mode.el?id=59b5723c9b613f14cd60cd3239cfdbc0d2343b18#n193). We cannot advice the `help-function` in this case since it is a lambda (and I am not sure there is any way to advice lambdas) so the only option left is advice `help-button-action`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your configuration. Maybe you have some lines for smooth scrolling in your .emacs... You can launch `emacs -q` and try your scenario for testing.
For smooth scrolling you can do something like this:

```
(setq scroll-margin 3)
(setq scroll-step 0)
(setq scroll-conservatively 10)
(setq scroll-preserve-screen-position t)
```

Comment: I dont think its config problem. The code for linked text is designed just to go to that location but not re aligning position.

Comment: You really should try with `emacs -q`. Every time I click on this kind of link, the defun is centered (I don't think it's a coincidence). I tries with C-h f goto-line, C-h f find-file and many others ...